# How to get id of clicked MatSlideToggle in a table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]

I have a table which includes some more than one mat-slide-toggle elements . When I change any of their value,I want to store which of them has changed and therefore I need id and true or false attribute of each one.I found FormControl to control event but it has no id property inside.Here what I tried below

**.HTML**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let not of notifications;let i = index"
    [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': (not.isFinished ? '#dddddd' : 'white') }">
  <th scope="row">{{i + 1}}</th>
  <td>{{not.task}}</td>
  <td>
    <section class="example-section">
      <mat-slide-toggle
        class="example-margin"
        [id]="i"
        [color]="color"
        [checked]="not.isFinished"
        [disabled]="not.isFinished"
        (toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event)"
        [formControl]="activate"
      >
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </section>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**.TS**

```
activate = new FormControl();

onToggleChange() {
  console.log(this.activate.value);
}
```

**UPDATE**
I solved the problem friends.Thanks for your all answers and I will share my solution here to help people who face this problem.I found                                     `(change)="onChange($event)"` and binded `ID` .

**HTML**

```
<td>
                        <section class="example-section">
                                <mat-slide-toggle
                                    [id]="i"
                                    class="example-margin"
                                    [color]="color"
                                    [checked]="not.isFinished"
                                    [disabled]="not.isFinished"
                                    (change)="onChange($event)"
                                    >
                                </mat-slide-toggle>
                              </section>
                </td>
```

**TScript**

```
onChange(value: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    console.log(value);
   }
```

Comment: You never add the `id` attribute in HTML template.

Comment: Which Id do you want? Are you talking about the notification Id?

Comment: It will not have an id property unless you assign it one. You can add the id property using the index.

Comment: I need the id of those MatSlideToggle element when its clicked

Comment: Why don't you add notification id and use that? What's your final goal?

Comment: `not.isFinished` is disabled and it is used as `checked` so if it is `not.isFinished=true` it will be disabled and you can select it, can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: I edited my question and added ID property which I tried before also

Comment: This looks like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Usually if you anwer yourself, you put it as an answer, not into the question.

Answer (score 0):

It will not have an id property unless you assign it one. You can add the id property using the index. From there you can add an event listener, i.e. click, or change and pass in the $event variable to get any information about the event that was just triggered.

Comment: I edited my solution and bined it like that :  [id]="i" . Then how can reach this when its clicked?

Comment: $event is a reserved word in Angular it will provide information about an event that was just triggered, such as the DOM element and properties, what type of event, etc. Console log or dir that event.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to pass data to the component function - you can pass any data you want from the template. You can pass the `i` or `not` if you like.

```
// template
(toggleChange)="onToggleChange(i, not)"
```

```
// component
onToggleChange(i: number, not) {

}
```

Note: `toggleChange` does not emit `$event`. Maybe you want to use `(change)` which emits type `MatSlideToggleChange` - [API docs](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api)

```
// template
(change)="onToggleChange($event, i, not)"
```

```
// component
onToggleChange(event: MatSlideToggleChange, i: number, not) {

}
```

Comment: that $event gives me undefined when I click any of them

Comment: Added a note why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need use FormArray.

```html
  <tr *ngFor="let not of notifications;let i = index" >
  <th scope="row">{{i + 1}}</th>
  <td>{{not.task}}</td>
  <td>
    <section class="example-section">
      <mat-slide-toggle
          [formControl]="forms.controls[i]">
      </mat-slide-toggle>
      </section>
  </td>
</tr>

<button (click)="console()">console values</button>
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Basic slide-toggles
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'slide-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'slide-toggle-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['slide-toggle-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SlideToggleOverviewExample {

  notifications = [
    {
      isFinished: false
    },
    {
      isFinished: true
    },
    {
      isFinished: false
    },
    {
      isFinished: true
    }
  ]

  forms;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.forms = this.formBuilder.array(
      this.notifications.map(e => this.formBuilder.control(e.isFinished))
    );
  }

  console() {
    console.log(this.forms.value)
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wte1qt?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.ts

Answer (score -1):

```
//component
 onToggleChange(change:MatSlideToggleChange, index: number)
 {
     console.log('the toggle value is: ' + change.value + ' the id is: ' + index);
 }

//template
 (toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event, i)"
```